# Classifier based on the format of input text

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification

I'm looking an algorithm (upon which to build a classifier) that can measure format similarity between two input texts. To put it broadly, a Levenshtein distance on format.

Consider for example having an application that collects logs data from different sources, and labels them by their format.

As another example consider an application that receives input as source code from different programming languages (let's assume they are not similar, so C and Haskell) and is able to classify them by their format.

Edit: additional examples

Consider the output from a `df -h` run

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   50G   12G   35G  26% /
devtmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    3.9G  596K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    3.9G  9.1M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                    3.9G  580K  3.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/fedora-home  178G   82G   87G  49% /home
/dev/sda1                477M  147M  301M  33% /boot
```

And that would be compared with an `ls -l`

```
total 68
drwxrwxr-x.  2 mhitza mhitza 4096 May 31 22:17 bin
drwxr-xr-x.  2 mhitza mhitza 4096 Jun  1 23:00 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x.  5 mhitza mhitza 4096 May 16 15:43 Documents
drwxr-xr-x. 12 mhitza mhitza 4096 Jun  4 19:08 Downloads
drwx------. 12 mhitza mhitza 4096 Mar 18 23:48 Dropbox
drwxrwxr-x. 12 mhitza mhitza 4096 Apr 30 02:08 Local
```

The algorithm should be able to infer that these two are different types of text "structures", and able to classify other types of incoming text for these groups.

The problem is that this is easy to do for a fixed set of formats, but I'd want to do it on any type of input.

Comment: Sounds like it would be an interesting question if you could clarify what you mean by "structure" more.  E.g. How is a structure obtained from an input text?  Is it represented by a string, a tree, what?  Is there one possible structure for any input text?  (Then the problem is easy.)  Or are there many possible structures, and you want to look for some pair of structures S1 and S2 that come from texts T1 and T2 respectively and that have minimum distance in some metric?

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify what structure means here

Comment: Good to have more examples, but it's still extremely unclear exactly what you mean by "structure".  Before we can attempt to find the Levenshtein distance between two "structures", we need fo first have an actual concrete string *representation* of those structures!

Comment: I don't know if levenshtein distance is appropriate tool here. Structure is here the *form* of the text, which has specific features (columns, range of characters per column, etc) that the algorithm would infer. I don't know how else to say it, but think of structure as with prose and poetry. You can visually distinguish them by their "form".

Comment: I belive "format" may be a more appropriate term.

Comment: Thanks @Alan I've applied your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of the question you are looking to find a way of representing arbitrary text such that it can be classified or clustered based on the format/structure of the data, not what values the data holds.

The naive approach would be to just gather a set of parsers for known document types and apply them in sequence, but (other than being unwieldy) I gather you don't want to do this as you want the method to be applicable to arbitrary structures (i.e.: new and or unsupported formats).

My first thought would be that as you are trying to classify based on structure not content, would be to try and simplify your documents into a symbolic representation.

For example the `df -h` output:

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   50G   12G   35G  26% /
...
```

Would become:

```
STRING, SEP, STRING, SEP, STRING, SEP, STRING, SEP, STRING, SEP, STRING
FILEPATH, SEP, MEMSIZE, SEP, MEMSIZE, SEP, MEMSIZE, SEP, PERCENTAGE, SEP, FILEPATH
...
```

This could be accomplised, for example, by applying a set of distinct pre-defined regular expressions (not forgetting an "I don't know" regex).

Just with this step it would be quite easy to recognize a `df -h` output, as it would have one header line and a bunch of table lines, which despite having different values, would all have the same symbolic representation.

To take it from this into being something useful you could throw a [bag of words model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) at it, and take each symbolic line as a single "word".

Following this method you could find a set of distinguishing common "words" (aka, symbolic lines) which you could use to create a numeric representation of each document. This could be done using something like [term frequency–inverse document frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf), but would probably benefit from using a supervised learning method (perhaps something like recursive feature elimination). From there it is a fairly simple case of throwing it into your favourite classification or clustering algorithm.

With just the examples given in the question it might look something like this:

`ls -l` output:

```
total 68
drwxrwxr-x.  2 mhitza mhitza 4096 May 31 22:17 bin
...
```

would become `ls -l` symbols:

```
STRING, SEP, NUMBERS
STRING, SEP, NUMBER, SEP, STRING, SEP, STRING, SEP, NUMBERS, SEP, STRING, SEP, NUMBER, SEP, TIME, SEP, FILEPATH
...
```

For the sake of brevity, lets refer to these symbolic lines as `L1` and `L2`, and simmilarly for the `df -h` symbolic lines `D1` and `D2`. This would mean we could represent the two example documents as follows:

```
ls -l: D1:0, D2:0, L1:1, L2:6
df -h: D1:1, D2:8, L1:0, L2:0
```